# Convert several 1D mat to a single 2D mat in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, mat

I am a new user to openCV. I have six 1200x1 Mat objects/variables. I want to make a single Mat variable which is  1200x6. How to do this?
For example, i have six mat objects a,b,c,d,e,f of 1200x1 size and now i want to make A = [a,b,c,d,e,f] , which is 1200x6 size. Please help

Comment: cv::Mat A; A.push_back(a); A.push_back(b) ... A.push_back(f); A.reshape(1, 6); will generate what you want. Alternatively you can use hconcat, but I think in this case it will be slower.

Comment: Perfect, Got it, thanks alot.. :)